# Importing Classes in Theos Tweak

Tags: ios, tweak, theos

I want to be able to create instances of other objects in my tweak. So basically I currently have something like

```
%hook MyView
-(id)myClass {
   id class = %orig;
   return class;
}
%end
```

What I want to do is use class like an instance of an object and be able to call methods of class and what not. I thought maybe I could import the header file which might help, however I get different problems because I'm pulling the header files using class-dump and I get all these references to XXUnknownSuperClass and leave me errors when I try to make the Tweak project

```
error: cannot find interface declaration for ‘XXUnknownSuperclass’, superclass of ‘Class’
```

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If a class has a shared instance then you can call any methods using:-

```
id class1 = [%c(ClassName) sharedInstance];
[class1 method];
```

You can also call and method if you are actually in the hooked code with:-

```
[self method];
```

The header file you have used that gives you that error has an error, i suggest you find another version from a different source if you need you use it.

If you are literally using the word class as in your example, this will cause an error also, use a different name like class1 or clas. Ignore this, if just an example.

Comment: Where is another place we can get the headers?

Comment: You can use these, they tend to be very reliable. https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders

Answer (score -1):

Try using this script instead: https://gist.github.com/Tyilo/3154222